# Using JavaScript proxy to consume WCF service on android

Tags: android, wcf, json, web-services

I need to consume some 3rd party WCF webservice that is normally used in a web application but this time from android.

I have the following function in the generated javascript proxy,

```
loginToW:function(email,password,succeededCallback, failedCallback, userContext) {
/// <param name="email" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="password" type="String">System.String</param>
/// <param name="succeededCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="failedCallback" type="Function" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
/// <param name="userContext" optional="true" mayBeNull="true"></param>
return this._invoke(this._get_path(), 'loginToW',false,{email:email,password:password},succeededCallback,failedCallback,userContext); },
```

I can't change anything in the service.
What's the easiest way to consume this kind of services in android? can I pass this javascipt to webView or should I construct a JSON message an post it using HttpClient? how to handle the callbacks ?

Thanks.

Comment: Better is that you construct a JSON message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructing json with gson makes it easy. But since I don't have access to the  service code I had to use http fox to see what the json actually looks like for each method.